# Trigger and TriggerHandler not covered by Test

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm faing an issue trying to test a trigger and its trigger handler.
The test insert record of the SObject corresponding to the trigger and it's handler but the they are not executed thus not covered.
I don't understand why.
Here is the code :

Trigger :

```
trigger TrainingRequestTrigger on EFX_TrainingRequest__c (before insert, before update) {
   System.debug('########## TrainingRequestTrigger');
  new TrainingRequestTriggerHandler().run();
}
```

Trigger Handler :

```
public class TrainingRequestTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {

// Fonctionnalité 003 sur CRM Edifixio

    public TrainingRequestTriggerHandler() {}

    /* context overrides */

    protected override void beforeInsert() {
        setRelatedUsers();
    }

    protected override void beforeUpdate() {
        setRelatedUsers();
    }

    /* private methods */

    //Used in Trigger methods : to update 3 users 
    private void setRelatedUsers(){
        EFX_TrainingRequest__c[] trainingRequests =  Trigger.new;
        setActivityManager(trainingRequests);
        setPracticeManagerAndTeamLeader(trainingRequests);

    }

    //setActivityManager updates BusinessActivityManager__c, if Business Activity is not null, with the first activity member whose role is 'Manager' in selected business activity
    private void setActivityManager(List<EFX_TrainingRequest__c> trainingRequests) {
        //Set all Business Activities Ids
        Set<Id> businessActivities = new Set<Id> ();
        for(EFX_TrainingRequest__c trainingRequest:trainingRequests){
            if(!businessActivities.contains(trainingRequest.BusinessActivity__c)){
                businessActivities.add(trainingRequest.BusinessActivity__c);
            }
        }

        //Map ManagersId by Business Activity Id
        Map<Id,Id> businessActivityManagerIds = new Map<Id,Id>();
        String recordTypeBAMember = Schema.SObjectType.EFX_BA_Member__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('BA_Membership').getRecordTypeId();

        for(EFX_BA_Member__c activityMember:[
                SELECT Id,Business_Activity__c,User__c
                FROM EFX_BA_Member__c
                WHERE Delivery_Role__c = 'Manager'
                AND Business_Activity__c IN :businessActivities AND RecordTypeId = :recordTypeBAMember
        ])
        {
            if(businessActivityManagerIds.get(activityMember.Business_Activity__c)==null){
                {
                    businessActivityManagerIds.put(activityMember.Business_Activity__c,activityMember.User__c);
                }
            }
        }

        //update BusinessActivityManager__c 
        for(EFX_TrainingRequest__c trainingRequest:trainingRequests){
            trainingRequest.BusinessActivityManager__c = businessActivityManagerIds.get(trainingRequest.BusinessActivity__c);
        }

    }

    //setPracticeManagerTeamLeader updates RequesterPracticeManager__c and RequesterTeamLeader__c with the first member of the 2 roles above the current user role
    private void setPracticeManagerAndTeamLeader(List<EFX_TrainingRequest__c> trainingRequests) {

        //create 2 lists of requester Ids : 
        //1 with "Team" members, who will have 2 approval steps 
        //1 with "Manager" members, who will have 1 approval step
        //use the standard field "Owner" of EFX_TrainingRequest__c to identify requester
        set<Id> requesterIdSet = new set<Id>(); //just used to avoid double check for users already managed
        set<Id> teamRequesterIdSet = new set<Id>();
        set<Id> managerRequesterIdSet = new set<Id>();
        map<Id,String> roleNameByUserId = new map<Id,String>();

        for(EFX_TrainingRequest__c trainingRequest:trainingRequests){
            requesterIdSet.add(trainingRequest.OwnerId);
        }

        Map<Id,Id> userInRoleAboveByUserId = getUserIdInRoleAboveInHiearchy(teamRequesterIdSet);

        for(User userWithRole: [select Id,UserRole.Name from User where Id in:requesterIdSet]){
            if (userWithRole.UserRole.Name.contains('Team')){
                teamRequesterIdSet.add(userWithRole.Id);

            }
            else if (userWithRole.UserRole.Name.endsWith('Manager')){
                managerRequesterIdSet.add(userWithRole.Id);
                 //when requester is a practice manager, after submit for approval, the status should be updated to "Pending - Team Leader Approval".And the if condition prevent request from status isn't updated to "Pending" after click submit for approval.
                for (EFX_TrainingRequest__c trainingRequest:trainingRequests)  {  
                    if(trainingRequest.Status__c=='Draft')
                    {
                    trainingRequest.Status__c='Draft - Practice Manager Request';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Create a map : Team requester Ids - practice manager Ids 
        Map<Id,Id> practiceManagerIdMap = getUserIdInRoleAboveInHiearchy(teamRequesterIdSet);

        // All context Manages are: 
        //      - Manager requesters.
        //      - Managers of Team Member requesters
        Set<Id> managersIdInContext =   new Set<Id>();
        managersIdInContext.addAll(managerRequesterIdSet);
        managersIdInContext.addAll(PracticeManagerIdMap.values());
        // All context Team Leaders are: 
        //      - Team Leader of manager requesters
        //      - Team Leader of manager of Team Member requesters
        //Create a map : Manager requester Ids - Team Leader Ids for all managers in context
        Map<Id,Id> teamLeadersIdInContext = getUserIdInRoleAboveInHiearchy(managersIdInContext);

        for (EFX_TrainingRequest__c trainingRequest:trainingRequests)
        { 
            Id practiceManagerId = practiceManagerIdMap.get(trainingRequest.OwnerId);
            if (practiceManagerId !=null){
                trainingRequest.RequesterPracticeManager__c = PracticeManagerId;

                // Get the teamLeader from context team leader
                Id teamLeaderId = teamLeadersIdInContext.get(practiceManagerId);
                If (practiceManagerId !=null){
                    trainingRequest.RequesterTeamLeader__c = TeamLeaderId;
                }
            }
            else {
                trainingRequest.RequesterPracticeManager__c = null;
                Id teamLeaderIdForManagerRequester = teamLeadersIdInContext.get(trainingRequest.OwnerId);
                if (teamLeaderIdForManagerRequester != null){
                    trainingRequest.RequesterTeamLeader__c = teamLeaderIdForManagerRequester;

                }
                else{
                    trainingRequest.RequesterTeamLeader__c = null;
                     //settings for the "Status"
                    if(trainingRequest.Status__c=='Draft')
                    {
                    trainingRequest.Status__c='Draft - Team Leader or DG Request';
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }  

    //returns parent user Id (first one of parent role in hierarchy) as value of map user Id - parent user Id
    private static Map<Id,Id> getUserIdInRoleAboveInHiearchy(set<Id> userIdSet){
        Map<Id,Id> parentRoleUserIdMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        for (User user: [select Id,UserRoleId,UserRole.ParentRoleId from User where Id IN :userIdSet]){
            if(!parentRoleUserIdMap.containsKey(user.Id)){
                parentRoleUserIdMap.put(user.Id,user.UserRole.ParentRoleId);
            }
        }

        Map<Id,Id> parentRoleRoleIdMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        for (UserRole userRole: [select Id, (Select Id from Users order by HR_DateOfHire__c asc Limit 1) from UserRole where Id IN :parentRoleUserIdMap.values()]){
            if(userRole.Users.size()>0 && !parentRoleRoleIdMap.containsKey(userRole.Users[0].Id)){
                parentRoleRoleIdMap.put(userRole.Id,userRole.Users[0].Id);
            }
        }

        //Construct return Map
        Map<Id,Id> parentUserIdMap = new Map<Id,Id>(); 
        for (Id userId:userIdSet)
        {   
            Id parentRoleRoleId = parentRoleUserIdMap.get(userId);
            if (parentRoleRoleId !=null){
                Id parentRoleUserId = parentRoleRoleIdMap.get(parentRoleRoleId);
                If (parentRoleUserId !=null){
                    parentUserIdMap.put(userId,parentRoleUserId);
                }
            }
        }

        return parentUserIdMap;
    }
}
```

Test :

```
@IsTest
public class TrainingRequestTriggerHandlerTest {
    private static testMethod void  testValidatorsAssignement(){
        List<EFX_TrainingRequest__c> myTrainingRequestList = new List<EFX_TrainingRequest__c>();

        Map<String,User> userListByTrigram = new  Map<String,User>();
        for(User myUser : [SELECT Id,Name,alias FROM User where alias in:new Set<String>{'YLU','EBT','JXU','MCN','IIE','DBE','THT','YHT'}]){
            userListByTrigram.put(myUser.alias,myUser);
        }
        Account acc = new Account(name='Akram', Type='Customer', EFX_Account_ID__c ='1234');
        insert acc;

        EFX_BusinessActivity__c sfdc = new EFX_BusinessActivity__c(name='salesforce',Type__c='Projects',Account__c=acc.id, Active__c=true);
        insert sfdc;
        String recordTypeBAMember = Schema.SObjectType.EFX_BA_Member__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('BA_Membership').getRecordTypeId();

        EFX_BA_Member__c sfdcManager = new EFX_BA_Member__c(Business_Activity__c=sfdc.Id,User__c=userListByTrigram.get('MCN').Id,Delivery_Role__c = 'Manager', RecordTypeId = recordTypeBAMember);
        insert sfdcManager;
        EFX_BA_Member__c sfdcMember = new EFX_BA_Member__c(Business_Activity__c=sfdc.Id,User__c=userListByTrigram.get('JXU').Id,Delivery_Role__c = 'Member', RecordTypeId = recordTypeBAMember);
        insert sfdcMember;


        //JXU asks for training in Oracle
        EFX_TrainingRequest__c req1 = new EFX_TrainingRequest__c(BusinessActivity__c=sfdc.Id,BusinessActivityManager__c=userListByTrigram.get('YLU').Id,OwnerId=userListByTrigram.get('JXU').Id,Subject__c='test',Motivation__c='test');
        myTrainingRequestList.add(req1);

        //Activity2: Oracle 
        EFX_BusinessActivity__c oracle = new EFX_BusinessActivity__c(name='oracle',Type__c='Projects',Account__c=acc.id, Active__c=true);
        insert oracle;



        EFX_BA_Member__c oracleManager = new EFX_BA_Member__c(Business_Activity__c=oracle.Id,User__c=userListByTrigram.get('YLU').Id,Delivery_Role__c='Manager', RecordTypeId = recordTypeBAMember);
        insert oracleManager;

        //Yann asks for training in Oracle
        EFX_TrainingRequest__c req2 = new EFX_TrainingRequest__c(BusinessActivity__c=oracle.Id,BusinessActivityManager__c=userListByTrigram.get('IIE').Id,OwnerId=userListByTrigram.get('YHT').Id,Subject__c='test',Motivation__c='test');
        myTrainingRequestList.add(req2);

        //AJI (manager of oracle) asks for training
        EFX_TrainingRequest__c req3 = new EFX_TrainingRequest__c(BusinessActivity__c=oracle.Id,BusinessActivityManager__c=userListByTrigram.get('IIE').Id,OwnerId=userListByTrigram.get('IIE').Id,Subject__c='test',Motivation__c='test');
        myTrainingRequestList.add(req3);

        //Commit
        Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(myTrainingRequestList,true);
        //Ensure that managers of Jiahuan are ok
        EFX_TrainingRequest__c[] jxuReq = [select Id,BusinessActivityManager__c,RequesterPracticeManager__c,RequesterTeamLeader__c from EFX_TrainingRequest__c where Id=:srList[0].getId()];
        System.assertEquals(1, jxuReq.Size());

        //Ensure that managers of Yan are ok
        EFX_TrainingRequest__c[] yhtReq = [select Id,BusinessActivityManager__c,RequesterPracticeManager__c,RequesterTeamLeader__c from EFX_TrainingRequest__c where Id=:srList[1].getId()];
        System.assertEquals(1, yhtReq.Size());

        //Ensure that team leader of AJI is ok
        EFX_TrainingRequest__c[] ajiReq = [select Id,BusinessActivityManager__c,RequesterPracticeManager__c,RequesterTeamLeader__c from EFX_TrainingRequest__c where Id=:srList[2].getId()];
        System.assertEquals(1, ajiReq.Size());

    }
}
```

Do you guys have any clue about this ?

Comment: Does the test pass? Is the trigger active?

Comment: You should use Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() methods in your test class. Maybe explore @TestSetup a bit?

Comment: @DavidReed Thank you the trigger was inactive. I feel dumb now. Thank you again for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first things to look for when a trigger is not receiving coverage are

1. Is the test passing?
2. Is the trigger being invoked by performing the correct DML operation?
3. Is the trigger active?

Per your comment, this time the issue was that the trigger was inactive.